# Setup Roundup with WSGI and Apache

Tags: apache2, debian, mod-wsgi, python-2.6, roundup

I was install Roundup 1.4 by Debian Squeeze official repo and want to run it with my Apache server using `mod_wsgi`. Host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName support.domain.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/roundup/support/apache/roundup.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess support.roundup user=roundup group=roundup threads=25
    WSGIProcessGroup support.roundup

    <Directory /var/roundup/support>
        <Files roundup.wsgi>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    # ... some logging configuration
</VirtualHost>
```

I was install tracker in `/var/roundup/support` using `roundup-admin install`, configure it and next initialise using `roundup-admin initialise`. Then I was created `apache/roundup.wsgi`:

```
from roundup.cgi.wsgi_handler import RequestDispatcher
tracker_home = '/var/roundup/support'
application = RequestDispatcher(tracker_home)
```

When opening my site at `http://support.domain.com` (ofcourse this url is bit different) I have HTTP response `500 Internal Server Error` and log with:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=17433): Exception occured processing WSGI script '/var/roundup/support/apache/roundup.wsgi'.
RuntimeError: response has not been started
```

What's going on? How to run roundup with wsgi (not cgi) properly? Or where to look why response has not been started?

### EDIT

---

Roundup's install manual says that wsgi handler would look like this:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

# obtain the WSGI request dispatcher
from roundup.cgi.wsgi_handler import RequestDispatcher
tracker_home = 'demo'
app = RequestDispatcher(tracker_home)

httpd = make_server('', 8917, app)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

But this make no response. Browser loading it forever without message or server log. I think starting another server from script running by apache module isn't good idea. So I tried another code sample:

```
from roundup.cgi.wsgi_handler import RequestDispatcher
tracker_home = '/var/roundup/support'
application = RequestDispatcher(tracker_home)

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
WSGIServer(application).run()
```

But this throws some errors like:

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
```

There must be a way to run my application from RequestDispatcher...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this issue](http://issues.roundup-tracker.org/issue2550668) this is an permission's problem. Solved using:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess support.roundup user=roundup group=roundup threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup support.roundup
```

where files in `/var/roundup/support/` has `roundup` as owner and group with appropriate access permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from roundup.cgi.wsgi_handler import RequestDispatcher
tracker_home = '/var/roundup/support'
application = RequestDispatcher(tracker_home)
```

All mod_wsgi needs is an 'application' object which is a valid WSGI application entry point.

You do not need to start a WSGI server or FASTCGI adapter yourself as you have been trying to do.

Comment: Above last edit I wrote that throws runtime error with message: `response has not been started`, but don't know why.